# How to prove that the MLE of a uniform distribution is biased using the formula given below?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, expected-value, unbiased-estimator

I've calculated the MLE of the uniform distribution on [0,theta] as maxi{Xi} but don't know how to prove it is biased. The formula I have learned to prove it is unbiased is E(θ^)-θ=0.

Was stuck on how to take expectation of max{xi} values. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Find the distribution of the maximum.  Doing so requires only applying probability axioms -- no extensive calculations or theorems are needed.

Comment: @whuber can you please ellaborate on how to do so? thanks

Comment: See the duplicate.  Alternatively, compare the maximum to $\theta$ itself; note that the maximum almost surely is *strictly less* than $\theta,$ and (immediately) draw the conclusion.